# Serialize a List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Let's suppose we have an:

```
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Items { get; set; }
```

How can we serialize it as follows:

```
<!--<SomeEnclosingElement>-->
    <Key1>Value1.ToString()</Key1>
    <Key2>Value2.ToString()</Key2>
    ...
    <KeyN>ValueN.ToString()</KeyN>
<!--</SomeEnclosingElement>-->
```

using `XmlSerializer`, if possible, without custom implementation of `IXmlSerializable`?

Please note two things:

- Element (tag) names varies from node to node
- No enclosing element needed at all (I commented it above just to better illustrate this requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement not to implement `IXmlSerializable`, you could add a `public XElement[]` surrogate property marked with [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) to your type:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Items { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XElement[] XmlItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (Items == null)
                return null;
            return Items.Select(p => new XElement(p.Key, (p.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString())).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            Items = Items ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(value.Length);
            foreach (var e in value)
            {
                Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(e.Name.LocalName, e.Value));
            }
        }
    }
```

The original property is marked with `[XmlIgnore]` while the surrogate property returns an array of `XElement` objects whose names are mapped from `KeyValuePair.Key` and whose values are mapped from `KeyValuePair.Value.ToString()`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TGNceD).